# Change background image when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, elementor

The background image of my landing needs to be changed when the button is clicked.

I´m a newbie on wordpress and don´t know how the background image on the landing could be changed.

I know that there is a possibility to work with JavaScript but I can´t find my button in the editor. Could someone help me step to step so that I can change the background image with other random images that I could use.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const yourButton = document.querySelector('#your-button-id');
const element = document.querySelector('.element'); //element where you want to change background image
const imageLink = 'www.domain.com/image-url.jpg'

yourButton.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
e.preventDefault();
element.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imageLink + ')';
});
```

change variables` selectors to yours, and if you click on button the primary background image will be changed